# No provisioned iPhone connected....!

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Hii all,

I tried to test my application on the simulator and it fails. Just the day before it was working fine. i checked in the organizer window.. all the provision certificates are installed, but still the color is Orange,. its not working. and when i try to debug the application it shows "No provisioned iPhone connected" error.

I got the same problem before, at that time i changed the name of the folder which specify the iphone version, but unfortunately i don't remember now where that folder is. Can anyone help me please.. or is there any alternative.

Thanks,

Shibin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two possibilities here. [As Alex says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979421/no-provisioned-iphone-connected/1979569#1979569), if you are trying to run on the Simulator then you need to switch your active SDK to one of the Simulator options. The screen shot is of a rather old version of the SDK but the principle is the same.

If, on the other hand, you are trying to run on a phone that has worked before you usually just need to reboot your handset. Sometimes the process that the debugger connects to gets in a state and doesn't respond. Restarting usually works.

Answer (score 0):

You can the *No provisioned device connected* error only when you try to test on the device. Did you check the active configuration of your project? In order to run the Simulator you should have the corresponding build configuration selected. See the screenshot: [alt text http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/7594/xcodeconfig.png](http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/7594/xcodeconfig.png)

Answer (score 0):

So you are seeing orange color status of the iphone in organizer? If it is the problem simply switch off your device and switch-on again. Try reconnecting the device. This solves my same problem most of the time.

Hope this helps.