# No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected

Tags: xcode

I just updated my Xcode to the latest version and am trying to run an app on my device but I get the following error:

No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make a search here... This question has been answered many times...

- [“No provisioned iPhone OS device is
  connected” after update to 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131641/no-provisioned-iphone-os-device-is-connected-after-update-to-4-0)

  [getting the error“ No provisioned
  iPhone OS device is connected” for
  iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849094/getting-the-error-no-provisioned-iphone-os-device-is-connected-for-iphone)

  [iPhone dev
  question: “No provisioned iPhone OS
  is connected” error, I don’t know
  what else to try for
  troubleshooting…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019666/iphone-dev-question-no-provisioned-iphone-os-is-connected-error-i-dont-know)

  [No
  provisioned iPhone connected…!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979421/no-provisioned-iphone-connected)

To give only a few...