# how to run apps in device in xcode 4?

Tags: iphone

Hay every one I'm working in iphone. recently I installed xcode 4 but i can not run my apps in device. I select run destination as ios device bu when I run my apps it say
 "No provisioned iOS devices are available. Connect an iOS device or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."  pls someone help me. any help will be appreciated. Thanx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4 -- "no provisioned iOS device is connected" with iPod touch 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443688/xcode-4-no-provisioned-ios-device-is-connected-with-ipod-touch-2)

Answer (score 5):

you need an active iOS developer program account. Otherwise you are only able to test your programs in the simulator!

to manage your devices, please read the following article:
[Managing Devices and Digital Identities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW2)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have provisioning certificates and all that, do what Sascha said.

If you do, you might be having a problem that I ran into. I was trying to run apps on an iPod touch 2g with iOS 4.2, and I got the "no provisioned iOS devices" problem, even though I had a provisioned device connected. So I went into my project settings and changed "build target" from iOS 4.3 to iOS 4.2, and once I did that, my device showed up.